# search() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

views.py

```
def search(request,csv_export):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        reports = Report.objects.filter(user__in=user_list).order_by('-created_date_time', '-id')
    ''''' 
    some code
    ''''''
    if csv_export:  
        response = HttpResponse(mimetype='text/csv')
        filename = "%s-%s.csv" % ('incident-reporter', datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % filename
        writer = UnicodeWriter(response, encoding='utf-8')
        writer.writerow(headerrow)
        for writerow in report_list:
            writer.writerow(writerow)
        return response        
    return render(request,'search.html',{'report':report})
```

urls.py

```
 urlpatterns = patterns(
     'incident.views',
     (r'^$', 'index'),
     (r'^search/$', 'search',{"csv_export": False}),
     (r'^csv_export/$', 'csv_export',{"csv_export": True}),
     (r'^what/$', 'what'),
     (r'^where/$', 'where'),
     (r'^when/$', 'when'),
     (r'^media/$', 'media'),
)
```

I am getting this error:

> "TypeError at /report/search/ search() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)"

See below my traceback:

```
Traceback:
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  23.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

Exception Type: TypeError at /report/search/
Exception Value: search() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

**Edit**: urls.py updated in question

Comment: Can you upload the `/report/search` url's view?

Comment: Can you post more of the urls.py?

Comment: Is that all you have in your urls.py?

Comment: @Bibhas,i updated the full urls.py

Comment: EDIT: wait, that might be the cause of django-debug-toolbar. ORIGINAL MESSAGE: @user2086641 What are the local variables `args` and `kwargs` in `_wrapped_view`? (There should be a detailed traceback on the error page if you use `DEBUG = True`.)

Comment: @knbk ohh thanks for your comment,i debugged and solved just.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is probably originated elsewhere (i think in an `{% url %}` call), but it should be easy to solve:

```
def search(request, csv_export=False):
```

then in urls.py:

```
(r'^search/$', 'search'),  # <- more elegant, isn't it?
(r'^csv_export/$', 'csv_export', {"csv_export": True}),
```

this provides a defult value for csv_export, if it's called without the argument.

if this doesn't solve your problem, you should post more details about your schema.